# Fill dataframe based on matching columns with another dataframe with duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two identical dfs one with data (& duplicates) the other without data. Let's call them `df1` and `df2`. However, `df2` has the same values as `df1` just deduplicated.

```
df1
  A    B    C            D    E
1 1    X1   Company X    JB   PhD
2 2    Y2   Company Y    RA   MsC
3 33   W2   Company W    JK   MsC
4 156  Z1   Company Z    SS   PhD
5 156  Z1   Company Z    SS   MsC 

df2 
  A    B    C            D    E
1 1    
2 2    
3 33   
4 156
```

I am trying to map the values in the other columns based on the first column of `df2`. But I want to merge the unique values in each column for each duplicated row in `df1` like below

```
df2
  A    B    C            D    E
1 1    X1   Company X    JB   PhD
2 2    Y2   Company Y    RA   MsC
3 33   W2   Company W    JK   MsC
4 156  Z1   Company Z    SS   PhD;MsC
```

Keep in mind that there are 27 columns in each df and each duplicated row for column 1 has only one unique value for that row. I got here because I've tried deduplicating `df1` using a mixture of `.drop_duplicates()` & `.unique()` on the columns in `df1` but the size of the tables makes it difficult to know I'm dropping the right values.

Comment: Do duplicates occur in all the columns or just in column `E`?

Comment: Duplicates can occur in all the columns

Answer (score 0):

You can make do with `groupby().agg()`:

```
df2[['A']].merge(df1.groupby('A', as_index=False)
              .agg(lambda x: ';'.join(x.unique())),
          on='A', how='left'
         )
```

Comment: This works as intended but is only returning 6 of the 27 columns for some reason

Comment: That's because your 6 columns are string type, which supports `':'.join`. The other columns are more likely numeric type.